# How can an HTML be contained, inline, within another HTML doc?

Tags: html

Is it possible wrap an HTML document within another, all within the same file? Such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
...
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>...</body>
  </html>
...
</html>
```

Why would I want to do that, you ask? (I don't :-) ) The [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function in PHP generates a full HTML document (to be used as a single call, on its own). I created an HTML document around it. Most browsers display this as I expected, but it is invalid HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>PHP Info</H1>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can solve this with PHP, but I was for an *HTML-only* solution; something like:

```
...
<xframe>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>...</body>
  </html>
</xframe>
...
```

I.e., something like `<iframe>` without the external reference.

Comment: How about messing with the `<object>` tag?

Comment: @csmckelvey — There's no practical difference between that and an iframe in this context.

Comment: Right... I was thinking that there must be a way to do this without the "target" content being external.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such.

The closest you could come would be to use an iframe with the src expressed as a `data:` scheme URL (which encodes the entire HTML document inside the URL itself) … but that would require `phpinfo()` to return a string of HTML instead of just outputting it.

Comment: Wrapping the `phpinfo();` call inside `ob_start();` and `$html = ob_ob_get_flush();` would do the trick in this case.